# how to disable and enable anchor in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I am using below code :

```
$(".ui-combobox-toggle").unbind("click");
```

Tt is disabling the button.

I had followed many other options like below it is not working. Using bind should work as of my knowledge but it did not.

I am not able to undo it again, I mean make it enable.

I used bind, removeData, data etc.

My major requirement now is I have a anchor button, I have to disable it on toggle button click and have to enable it on click toggle button again.

But they did not work. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**To disable a anchor:**

```
$("a").off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**Then when you need to enable it again:**

```
$("a").off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    return true;
});
```

**Sample here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/38YPU/

Comment: it is disabled, but not enabling. seems like it has the same problem i got with unbind and bind

Comment: ur fiddle is fine but check my code i dont know why? its behaving strange....

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery's [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

Example:

```
$('.ui-combobox-toggle').on('click', handler);
$('.ui-combobox-toggle').off('click', handler);
```

Comment: it is working for enable, but for disable it performs click operation and then getting disabled...